# Grails Entity without persist

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a domain class in grails... How do I get gorm to leave out this entity when it create the db? Just leave it alone.

Answer (score 14):

If i understood, u want not create table from domain class? If yes, use this code inside domain class:

```
static mapWith = "none" // disable persisting into database
```

Comment: The other answers to this question are fine and helpful, but this one is strictly the correct answer to the question.

Comment: And the default value for `mapWith` is `"GORM"`. See [the grails source](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/31af2108f171534edca3f6f15391364ee1fb2641/grails-core/src/main/groovy/org/grails/core/DefaultGrailsDomainClass.java)

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like you don't need it to be a domain class then.  You could just make it a POGO in the src/groovy file.  If my assumptions here are wrong please explain further what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Command Objects.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects

They provide the data binding and validation of domain classes, but do not map to the database.

Comment: You're taking advantage of a side-effect that command objects become validateable. It's better to create a src/groovy class and annotate it with `grails.validation.Validateable`

Comment: The Grails documentation on Command Objects specifically notes the validation feature, so it doesn't look like they are treating it as a side-effect.

Comment: You have to declare the command object in a controller to make it a command object. If you don't use it as a command object but just take advantage of its validation features as a non-persistent domain class, it's a side effect.